# java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method com.sap.isa.core.eai.BackendConfig.getId() of a null object

Tags: java, migration, crm, netweaver

I'm migrating a SAP B2B Commerce project from version 7.0 to 7.4, with the previous version of Java 1.4 to 1.7.

I can't see the login page, instead I see this:

> 500 Internal Server Error message:
>
> Error: ISA Framework: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method com.sap.isa.core.eai.BackendConfig.getId() of a null object loaded from local variable 'config'

But after a search in my files, I never see the variable `'config'` or the `com.sap.isa.core.eai.BackendConfig` import.

Where is the problem located? and how I can solve this issue?
Is this problem unrelated to my components?

**UPDATE**

Now the error message changed to this:

> ```
> /usr/sap/CRP/DVEBMGS26/j2ee/cluster/apps/sap.com/home~icss_s7/servlet_jsp/icss_s7/work/JEE_jsp_user_logon_login_1509734170000.java:448: cannot find symbol
>    symbol  : class Iterator
>    location: class JEE_jsp_user_logon_login_1509734170000
>                                    Iterator it = langTree.iterator();
> ```

I did change nothing at all, just refreshed the page, at least I get five similar errors about not being able to find the class symbol. This can be easily be fixed to make the necessary imports but I had search for such class, and it's not in the project, not sure if this class `JEE_jsp_user_logon_login_1509734170000.java` is generated somewhere else, or is unrelated to my components.

Comment: Hello @J.A.  did you get this resolved?  I am not 100% sure, but I believe the class reference is in the J2EE environment for the 7.4.  did you do a complete copy-down into the NWDS?  are you able to test in a development environment to see if the issue persists in an upgraded server environment rather than your local client?

Comment: No, i'm still with this problem, about the second question not sure about it, because i wasn't involved in the process of initial migration, i'm just fixing some issues, i'm gonna ask. 
About the third question i'm new to sap and all this, not sure how to do that..

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've had to deal with the NetWeaver environment. Just loaded my old project up. It is not J2EE at all. Iterator is in the java utility class.

try importing to your class/page using:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
```

***edit:***

My misunderstanding.  The **JEE_jsp_user_logon_login_1509734170000.java** should be an application code file within your solution.  I cannot say for sure, since each implementation differs by setup. They could have chosen to customize the login, or use the defaults in the masthead.

*disclaimer: we are still in 7.0, so your environment may differ*

For our implementation (custom), and the assumption that your environment has custom masthead/login as well:

You would need to access your repository:

- Go to your portal (i.e. mydomain.com:00000/irj/portal)
- System Administration
- Portal Runtime
- Browse Deployment

you would then need to locate/download the appropriate .PAR file *(file extension changed to .EAR in 7.3 I believe)*.  You can then import the existing component into your solution if it did not already exist.  Then make your changes, and update.

The "JEE_jsp_user_logon" part of the file name should get you into the right area when searching your repo, the rest I would assume is the serial stamp for caching and version control.

Hopefully this helps.

**this may help: *scroll down to "Modifying the logon page"***
http://www.keytosmart.com/netweaver-7-3-portal-started-part-2-nwds-logon-page/

Comment: yes, but `This can be easily be fixed to make the necessary imports but I had search for such class, and it's not in the project, not sure if this class **JEE_jsp_user_logon_login_1509734170000.java** is generated somewhere else, or is unrelated to my components.`

Comment: modified response. but unfortunately it could be either generated OR a custom component.  Depending on the old system, migration, etc.

Comment: I just found a link (added to the response) that should be able to get you to the right place in your environment.

Comment: How i can identify my portal address? Or can be it accesed from netweaver? also how i can identify the par file i need?

Comment: It would have to be provided to you by your management.  It is usually something like "https://[server]portal:5000?/irj/portal" (at least in 7.0).  Finding the PAR (remember, post-migration to 7.3 will be EAR not PAR) is a bit more tricky as it's location depends entirely on how your environment is set up. But once you are in the repository Root\WEB-INF is the top directory where you will need to look.

Comment: Hey i did try your solution, now i have the first error message i posted X/, the other page still has the same "cannot find symbol".

Comment: You were able to find the component in the repository, Imported it to NWMS, added the includes for the java utilities? And it still doesn’t recognize the symbol?  Also, you stated “the other page” these may be two mutually exclusive issues.